# Socket.io countdown

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to set a countdown on my express app and access it from react.
I figured out that I had to use socket.io for this and came up with the following code.
It works correctly but I know that I'm doing something wrong which would cause issues in the future.

- Client code:

```
function App() {
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        // should this be http://... or ws://... ?
        const socket = io("http://localhost:3001");
        socket.on("timer", (newTimer) => {
            setTimer(newTimer);
        });
        
        // The timer is stuck at the initial state (300) until I remove this return part which sometimes causes an error in the console saying insufficent resources
        return () => {
            socket.disconnect();
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>{timer}</h1>
        </>
    );
}
```

I am not sure this is the right way to do it in the server so I'd like to know which things I'm doing wrong here aswell.

- Server code:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);

// SOCKET IO

const io = new Server(server, { cors: { origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL } });
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(`${socket.id} is connected.`);
});

let timerValue = 5 * 60;
const countDown = () => {
    timerValue--;
    io.emit("timer", timerValue);
    console.log(timerValue);
};
setInterval(countDown, 1000);

// ROUTES

app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/auth", messageRoutes);

// CONNECTION

dbConnect().then(() => {
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6001;
    server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`));
});
```